# stop executing another before one gets completed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using $.ajax inside the for loop  in jquery.

```
for(var i=0; i < 2; 1++)
{

$.ajax({
url :"/models/getdata"+i
dataType:"json"
success:function(data)
{
}
});

}
```

before going success function for i=0; i=1 comes and performing the ajax request for this value. i want next iteration need to wait until current one gets completed.

that means one ajax request successfully completed and then it will increment the i value then start the next iteration.

consider another scenario also

```
function A()
{
$.ajax code

}
/////another operation
```

same here function A() need to wait until its ajax post get completed. but in my case it goes to next code start executing how can i stop further execution before current function gets completed. like sleep  concept in C#

how can i do this ?

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 3):

A simple generic solution :

```
var i=0;
(function doOne(){
    $.ajax({
        url :"/models/getdata"+i
        dataType:"json"
        success:function(data){
            if (++i<2) doOne();
        }
    });
})();
```

For your second case, you may use the [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) returned by $.ajax :

```
function A() {
   return $.ajax(...)
}

A().done(function(){
   // some code executed after the ajax call finished
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set `async: false` in the ajax call

Comment: aync attribute used to specify whether full post or ajax post not for this one.

Comment: no it won't go further without executing the ajax request first! that is why async false

Answer (score 0):

This method could be the best way to handle this problem.

```
$.when(*AJAX CALL*)
    .then(function() { // Function to run after ajax is completed
});
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, all requests are sent asynchronously when we use `$.ajax`.  By asynchronously, I meant, web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. But you want execution to be stopped until your request is complete so set `async` to 'false'.

Use this -

```
$.ajax({
    url :"/models/getdata"+i
    dataType:"json",
    async: false,
    success:function(data)
    {
    }
 });
```

Comment: what is the use of async : false ?

Comment: it makes sure that next line wont execute until this ajax call is completed

Comment: @SivaRajini then use dystroy solution.